# Simple.Data coalesce operation in select statement

Tags: simple.data

can any one help on translating below T-SQL statement to

Simple.Data query

select isnull(A.SomeValue,B.SomeValue),T.Id
from Table1 T1
left outer join ATable A on T1.AID = A.Id
left outer join BTable B on T1.BId = B.Id

Answer (score 0):

Simple.Data doesn't support coalescing in T-SQL. The standard way to get around this is to put the query in a stored procedure and then use Simple.Data to call the sproc. Details for that can be found [enter link description here](http://simplefx.org/simpledata/docs/pages/Tasks/UsingSprocs.html).